# Can the remote app run on a higher resolution

Tags: 8thwall-xr

Is there a way to increase the resolution of the remote app? Not sure if the low resolution is a result of intended restrictions for the remote or just poor internet speed. It's mostly that I have some GUI text elements which are hard to read because of it.

At the moment, I'm using the remote app on a 9.7" iPad Pro running iOS 11.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way of increasing the resolution of the of the remote app.

Comment: Too bad, I'll resolve the issue from a different angle then. Thank you for your time and help :o)